# Send email based on two cells in a specific google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an email if a cell in column 3 is yes and the cell in column 2 is equal to 200 in a specific sheet.
Here is what I have:

```
function sendMailEdit3(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 3 || e.value != "Yes" & e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue() == 200) return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,10).getValues();

  let n = rData[0][3];

  let loc = rData[0][1];

  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");

  let msg = "Transfer Order " + n + " is ready for pickup for warehouse " + loc + " as of " + now;

  GmailApp.sendEmail("email address", "Transfer Order Ready for Pickup", msg)
}
```

The specific sheet name is "inbound schedule"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
rData.forEach((r,i) => {
  if(r[1] == 200 && r[2] == "yes") {
    //Your fill the rest
    GmailApp.sendEmail("email address", "Transfer Order Ready for Pickup", msg) }
  })
}
```

Comment: thank but what I am really looking for is how to use a code just for a specific tab which in my case the name of the tab I want it to work on is called "inbound schedule" how can i implement the sheet name into the code?